# nodejs using mongoskin to connect mongo database running on bitnami E2C instance is always connecting to "admin" database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bitnami, mongoskin

I am using Nodejs at server using mongoskin and using cluster mongo database. I am using EC2 bitnami to built all the servers. From the application log, I print the database connection string which is as follow (Please ignore the ip address, i just put garbled value)

```
mongodb://username:password@22.344.345.444:27017,username:password@44.55.665.44:27017,username:password@23.543.345.345:27017/mydb?replicaSet=myDBReplicaCluster
```

Its very surprising to me that it always connect to "admin" database. It is not connecting to the "mydb" database as defined in the connection string. I have tried everything however not able to understand the problem. Following are all details
node module used:

```
"dependencies": {
       "express": "4.9.8",
       "body-parser": "1.9.0",
       "connect-busboy": "0.0.2",
       "cookie-parser": "1.3.3",
       "express-session": "1.9.0",
       "passport": "0.2.1",
       "passport-local": "1.0.0",
       "connect-flash": "0.1.1",
       "connect-mongoskin": "*",
       "morgan": "1.4.0",
       "ejs": "1.0.0",
       "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
       "mongodb": "1.4.19",
       "mongoskin": "1.4.4",
       "string": "2.2.0",
       "unzip": "0.1.11",
       "node-fs":"0.1.7",
       "xml2js":"0.4.4",
       "log4js":"0.6.21",
       "helmet":"0.5.2",
       "csurf":"1.6.3",
       "underscore":"1.7.0",
       "validator":"3.22.2",
       "elasticsearch":"*"

   },
   "devDependencies": {
       "grunt": "0.4.5",
       "chai": "1.9.2",
       "mocha": "1.21.5",
       "karma": "0.12.24",
       "grunt-contrib-copy": "0.7.0",
       "grunt-contrib-clean": "0.6.0",
       "grunt-contrib-uglify": "0.6.0",
       "grunt-contrib-jshint": "0.10.0",
       "grunt-simple-mocha": "0.4.0",
       "grunt-exec": "0.4.6",
       "karma-script-launcher": "0.1.0",
       "karma-chrome-launcher": "0.1.5",
       "karma-firefox-launcher": "0.1.3",
       "karma-ie-launcher": "0.1.5",
       "karma-jasmine": "0.1.5",
       "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "0.1.4",
       "karma-story-reporter": "0.2.2",
       "grunt-karma": "0.9.0",
       "grunt-cli": "0.1.13",
       "karma-sauce-launcher": "0.2.10",
       "phantomjs": "1.9.11",
       "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "0.1.1",
       "node-inspector": "0.7.4",
       "protractor": "*",
       "grunt-protractor-runner": "1.1.4",
       "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "0.3.0",
       "grunt-bump": "0.0.16",
       "node-gyp":"*",
       "grunt-sass":"*",
       "frisby":"*",
       "jasmine-node":"*",
       "grunt-jasmine-node":"*",
       "grunt-contrib-watch":"*"
   }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection string is not formatted correctly according to the [MongoDB URI format](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/).

You should not have the username & password repeated; the correct format should be:

```
mongodb://username:password@22.344.345.444:27017,44.55.665.44:27017,23.543.345.345:27017/mydb?replicaSet=myDBReplicaCluster
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Today I got to test this and worked :-)